# NextJs: How to use dynamic hostnames in api calls instead of .env variables

Tags: dynamic, next.js, environment-variables, hostname

I am building a NextJs app: How to use dynamic hostnames in api calls instead of .env variables?

For example sometimes in my local dev environment the app sometimes runs in port 3001. How do I accommodate such scenarios by dynamically passing the appropriate hostname during requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [next-absolute-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-absolute-url). From the docs:

> This module enables you to easily get the protocol and host of your
> Next.js app, both on the server and the client. Optionally, you can
> set a localhost variable, which is useful for local development if you
> have local lambda functions running on a different port.

```
  import absoluteUrl from "next-absolute-url";

  // in express we have req.get('host')
  const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);
```